# general difference between pip dependencies and conda dependencies

Tags: python, pandas, pip, dependencies, conda

I've been trying to find the answer to this for a while and can't seem to google the right stuff. I've learned some things about pip and conda, but still have this lingering question. Why are the dependencies that are installed different? For example, when I installed pandas with pip (clean environment) and then did a pip freeze, it listed 6 packages having been installed. When I did the same thing, but with conda (clean environment) and did conda list, it listed 30ish packages having been installed. I don't understand why there is this difference. Especially looking at the conda list, I don't understand why something like sqlite would be required to make pandas function.

The only hunch I have that seems to somewhat make sense based on what I've learned so far is that conda installs required packages and recommended packages. Since conda is more for scientific computing, it goes ahead and installs things that generally complement each other. While pip literally only installs the bare minimum to make pandas functional. If I'm way off base here, please let me know as I'm just trying to better understand what's going on.

Context for the question, the new engineering company I work out requires I use miniconda, which is fine and I like it so far. I generally use python make some custom tools to use in my field of engineering and use pyinstaller to wrap them in an executable so that people don't need to have python in order to use them (I find this to be the best way to get some stubborn engineers interested in what python can do). So, extra packages that I don't need just increases the baggage that pyinstaller has to deal with, so if I can avoid them, then that's what I'd like to do. I'm tempted to use the --no-deps to force only getting the packages I think I need, but I'd like to learn more about what conda is doing before I go subverting its recipe. Thanks!

Comment: I think the interesting work to do here is: does it make a difference? That is, try building something from pyinstaller where all the packages are from PyPI versus all the packages from Conda (Python itself can come from Conda in both cases). Is there a difference in the two binaries afterward?

Comment: There is a difference. Without going into detail, pyinstaller via pip was about 50mb when I zipped all the files for distribution and pyinstaller via conda was about 250mb when I zipped all the files for distribution. I will say, packaging it with pyinstaller is a bit slower, but the .exe itself seems to run just as fast. So, in that regard, I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 2):

> `pip` is the package installer for python source:(https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

> Conda is an open source package management system and environment management system source:(https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)

One of the key differences between `pip` and `conda` is the fact that `pip` manages only python packages, while conda is a general purpose package manager.

For a fresh environment with only `pip` and `python` installed explicitly by `conda`, we can see in `pip list`:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.1.2
setuptools 67.7.2
wheel      0.40.0
```

and in `conda list`

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
pip                       23.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.4          h2628c8c_0_cpython    conda-forge
setuptools                67.7.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                hb25d44b_16    conda-forge
vc14_runtime              14.34.31931         h5081d32_16    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.34.31931         hed1258a_16    conda-forge
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
```

As we can see, `conda list` contains `python`, `pip`, but also the linraries they depend upon, as these are managed by `conda` as well and are by design not included in the python package, but `pip` will not know about them

Comment: Also, many PyPI packages use wheels to provide their dependencies statically. So, they're just hiding many of the non-Python dependencies (and duplicating them, since they aren't shared across packages).

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. Thanks for the responses!